# Logistic regression after a 3 year follow up where successful people can leave the sample

Tags: logistic, survival, multinomial-logit

I have data tracking the outcomes of young people participating in an intervention project (between the ages of 12-16). In 2016, data was taken of all young people who had joined the project that year. These included children of a range of ages. On a 3 year follow up, we then recorded who had dropped out of the project. I want to run a logistic regression to measure what variables predict the probability of a young person dropping out of the project.

Those who had dropped out were coded as a 1 for failure.

Anyone who was still in the study was coded as a 0 (success). These cases are technically right censored.

However, at age 16 people must leave the project, but this is called a successful outcome as they stayed in the scheme during secondary school. These are described as 'graduates'. These people could have turned 16 before the 3 year follow up (for instance in 2017).

My question is, am I ok to code graduates as a 0 also, as they are not deemed a failed outcome? My hypothesis is simply to test the probability of failure occurring.

Or would it be more appropriate to use a multinomial regression, coding graduates as a 2? If possible, I would prefer to use a logistic regression to keep my model as simple as possible.

For further context, I am running this analysis alongside a competing risk regression (CRR) (survival analysis).
The motivation is for the CRR to determine variables which lead to individuals dropping out more quickly. The logistic regression will define which variables best predict drop out.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you think the regression coefficients from the survival analysis approach won't tell you which variables best predict drop out? You can do scaled feature importance (i.e. multiply coefficient by sd of feature) in the same way you can with logistic regression.

Comment: Hi Cliff AB, thanks for commenting. I must add I am very new to running survival analysis models. I wanted to run the logistic regression in a mixed effects structure to test for nesting in my data. This does not seem possible to compute in R for a CRR.  Do you think I would still be justified in running the two separate models for my report?

Comment: there are mixed effects models for survival models as well. For example, R has the `coxme` package.

Comment: Thanks Cliff AB, I had considered running this but it uses a Cox regression instead of a Fine and Gray model. This would mean taking a cause-specific hazard approach to the competing risk as opposed to a sub-distribution hazard. I am currently not aware of any other packages for a ME CRR. I was hoping to by-pass this by using the ME logistic regression and CRR combo. However, I am now leaning more towards the coxme approach.